# Deleting dynamic array messes up my results

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm setting my old array to the value of the new array
`array = newArray;`

and if I call 
`delete[] newArray;`

after, It messes up the results. However, If I don't delete, then the results come out right. Where am i going wrong? Below shows the array being printed before calling the delete function, the second part is calling it after.

```
2
4
6
2
4
6

3.18449e-314
3.18449e-314
6
2
4
6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm setting my old array to the value of the new array `array = newArray;`

That's not how you copy an array in C++. That just assigns the value of the pointer. You will need to:

1. Allocate memory for the new array.
2. Copy the elements from the old array to the new array.

Then you are free to call `delete` on the old array.

You can avoid all the trouble if you have the option of using `std::vector` or `std::array`. If you do, then you can use:

```
array = newArray;
```

Of course, that would also mean that you don't have to use

```
delete [] newArray;
```

Comment: `std::array` hasn't been covered, however your answer solved my problem. I had to `delete [] array;` and create a `new` array.

Comment: @JohnSnow *I had to delete [] array; and create a new array* -- Read the answer carefully.  You should allocate the array first, copy the contents of the old array to the new array, **then** delete the old array.  The reason why is this -- what if the call to `new[]` fails after you've deleted your data?  There is no recovery from that since your data is gone.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the comment I wrote wasn't clear. I'm now calling `array = new type[size];` after calling `delete [] array;` then setting `array = newArray;`

Comment: @JohnSnow, that's a memory leak. The value returned by `new type[size]` is now permanently lost as far as your program is concerned.

Comment: @RSahu should there still be a leak if it was contained in a function call?

Comment: @JohnSnow, yes.

Comment: I just ran the program with valgrind and got the message no leaks were possible. I think I may be miscommunicating. I'll try to edit with my code after it's graded.

Comment: @JohnSnow *I just ran the program with valgrind* -- Until you post your full program, what you've described up to this point is incorrect coding.  Don't rely on third-party tools for small, obvious things like this.  That tool can lead you down the wrong road.  The way it should be done:  `type *temp = new type[size];` then copy the data from `array` to `temp`.  Once this is done, it is now safe to `delete [] array;` and do the final assignment of `array = temp;`.